# C# Exceptioncontext's exception converting to custom exception gives null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, asp.net-web-api2

When trying to convert context.Exception to DomainException, i always getting null

```
public class DomainExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        DomainException domainException = context.Exception as DomainException; // context.Exception is not null whereas
        if (domainException != null) // always null
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainException.Message);

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(json);
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my custom exception class looks like

```
public class DomainException : Exception
{
    internal DomainException(string businessMessage)
        : base(businessMessage)
    {
    }
}
```

I have tried adding a new construct in DomainException class to take exception parameter as follows.

```
public class DomainException : Exception
{
    internal DomainException(string businessMessage)
        : base(businessMessage)
    {
    }
    public DomainException(Exception ex) : base(ex.Message)
    {

    }
}
```

No errors but getting a null when converting to my customexception(domainException)?

Comment: `null` means it's not `DomainException`

Comment: I have to modify the DomainException class to accept the exception context which i have mentioned in third code block, i have made a change in my class but it is null still.

Comment: Operator [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) doesn't actually convert anything, it only tries to cast and returns `null` if the types are incompatible. In your case it means `context.Exception` is not a derivative of `DomainException`. You need to explicitly call the constructor to do the conversion you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just directly converting it through 'as' , you need to convert it explicitly as your type DomainException does not match with context.Exception.

So, you may convert it like below:

```
DomainException dex = new  DomainException(context.Exception.Message);
```

And further you can use 'dex' wherever you want.